# Would tensorflow run on Ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: software-installation, compatibility

We're buying a gaming laptop, probably Lenovo Y700, for the company and dual-booting it. I'm going to install Ubuntu MATE in order to run tensorflow and some OpenAI platforms.

Azure says that if you want to run tensorflow on its cloud you need to install Ubuntu 16.04 and you mustn't update or upgrade anything otherwise it won't work, and indeed I broke my installation that way.

Is that true for all Ubuntu systems or is it just the case with the Azure image? Can I install Ubuntu MATE 17.04 and just do what I want with it? I'd probably use docker anyway but I'm just double checking on what happens if I don't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it works. Double check your computer also has nvidia hardware, OpenCL is still a no-go. BTW tensorflow/gym alsos run on windows, however some OpenAI gym environments may have problems with dependencies.

If you want to build use python3, gcc5, cuda8, cudnn6. This is a config I have tested, and I know that it works.